# dotnet core 2.1, 3.1 how to connect oracle 11g

Tags: .net, oracle

Currently, I need to connect with oracle 11g   : version 11.2.0.1
I used .net Core 2.1 and 3.1, I waste a lot of time, but, I can not success when get and work with oracle 11g.

I saw oracle notice support with 12c, I try to use example of oracle 12c  for connect with oracle 12c, but when it's connect, can not get table. (I've newbie for work with oralce, I think It's like mssql, I connected with mysql and select * from product, but, It's told: don't see the table?)

But, the lasted, I want to connect with oracle 11g, what's should I do? only one way is must buy the driver of https://www.devart.com/ ?

Comment: I think it would help if you share that how you are trying to connect?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the latest ODP.NET only worked with 12c+. If it doesn't work with 11g then it should fail when you try to connect, not silently fail to find a table. Can you try the most fully qualified name you can for the table i.e. include the user name and / or the schema name too? (I forget how Oracle namespacing works)